# C#: String -> MD5 -> Hex

Tags: c#, hash, md5

in languages like PHP or Python there are convenient functions to turn an input string into an output string that is the HEXed representation of it.

I find it a very common and useful task (password storing and checking, checksum of file content..), but in .NET, as far as I know, you can only work on byte streams.

A function to do the work is easy to put on (eg http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/c-code-snippet-creating-an-md5-hash-string/), but I'd like to know if I'm missing something, using the wrong pattern or there is simply no such thing in .NET.

Thanks

Comment: Consider using SHA-256 instead of MD5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method you linked to seems right, a slightly different method is showed on the [MSDN C# FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2006/10/09/How-do-I-calculate-a-MD5-hash-from-a-string_3F00_.aspx)

A comment suggests you can use:

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(string, "MD5");
```

Comment: But please *don't* use the code shown in the FAQ, as is uses Encoding.ASCII and will therefore treat all non-ASCII characters as "?" - making it a pretty awful hash.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can only work with bytes (as far as I know).  But you can turn those bytes easily into their hex representation by looping through them and doing something like:

```
myByte.ToString("x2");
```

And you can get the bytes that make up the string using:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
```

So it could be done in a couple lines.

Answer (score 5):

One problem is with the very concept of "the HEXed representation of [a string]".

A string is a sequence of *characters*. How those characters are represented as individual bits depends on the encoding. The "native" encoding to .NET is UTF-16, but usually a more compact representation is achieved (while preserving the ability to encode any string) using UTF-8.

You can use [`Encoding.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx) to get the encoded version of a string once you've chosen an appropriate encoding - but the fact that there *is* that choice to make is the reason that there aren't many APIs which go straight from string to base64/hex or which perform encryption/hashing directly on strings. Any such APIs which *do* exist will almost certainly be doing the "encode to a byte array, perform appropriate binary operation, decode opaque binary data to hex/base64".

(That makes me wonder whether it wouldn't be worth writing a utility class which could take an encoding, a `Func<byte[], byte[]>` and an output format such as hex/base64 - that could represent an arbitrary binary operation applied to a string.)